# T-SQL - Check if ID appears in a date or in a later date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, retention

I have two tables, one looks like this that measures when a user joined:

```
 userId        Date     
 ----      -------------  
   1        01-01-2013       
   2        01-01-2013       
   3        01-01-2013       
   4        01-01-2013       
   5        01-01-2013 ....
```

And another one that looks like this that has events related to the users:

```
  id    userID    event        Date     
 ----  -----     ---------    ------
   1    1        open         01-01-2013       
   2    2        close        01-02-2013       
   3    2        move         01-03-2013       
   4    3        open         01-04-2013       
   5    5        move         01-05-2013 ....
```

I want to obtain another table, that given a date it obtains how many of the users that joined in that date had an event in the next consecutive dates or in a later date and group them by those consecutive dates.

So for example in my first table every user joined the same date, so if I query for that date I would like to obtain this:

```
userCount        Date     
 ----      -------------  
   4        01-01-2013       
   3        01-02-2013       
   3        01-03-2013       
   2        01-04-2013       
   1        01-05-2013 ....
```

in the first row the userCount it's 4 because `userId: 1,2,3,5` appear in that date or in a later date, in the next row userCount it's 3 because `userId: 2,3,5`
appear in a later date and `userId 1` doesn't appear in that date or in a later date, and so on.

How could I query to obtain those kind of results?

What I'm trying to measure it's the [Unbounded retention](https://amplitude.com/blog/2016/08/11/3-ways-measure-user-retention/) of users.

Comment: Don't have an example were everyone joins on the same date.

Comment: What have you tried? sample data will help things along here

Comment: Your event table only has 4 users in it. Is that a typo? Or are you still expecting to get back a user count of 5 at some point?

Comment: I just edited the description. @Xedni you were right I had a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd approach it. set up sample data:

```
declare @JoinDate date = '01-01-2013'

declare @users table (UserId int primary key, JoinDate date)

insert into @Users
values
    (1, '01-01-2013'),
    (2, '01-01-2013'),
    (3, '01-01-2013'),
    (4, '01-01-2013'),
    (5, '01-01-2013')

declare @events table 
(
    Id int primary key,
    UserId int,
    EventName varchar(10),
    EventDate date
)

insert into @Events
values
    (1,1,'open','01-01-2013'),
    (2,2,'close','01-02-2013'),
    (3,2,'move','01-03-2013'),
    (4,3,'open','01-04-2013'),
    (5,5,'move','01-05-2013')
```

First step is to get the list of users who joined on the specified date (in this case, it happens to be everyone, but I'm assuming that's not always true). Then join that result to events on `UserId`. Since you only care about events which happened on or after the join date, you can include that condition in the join between the two

```
select e.*
from @users u
inner join @Events e
    on u.UserId = e.UserId
        and e.EventDate >= @JoinDate
where u.JoinDate = @JoinDate
```

from there, you could self join that result set joining on an inequality between the two `EventDate` fields. In other words, if there are 4 users on one date, all 4 users will be propagated forwards in time to any rows beyond that date. By doing a `count(distinct UserId)`, you can then arrive at the distinct number of users who had an event on or past that day.

```
;with src as
(
    select e.*
    from @users u
    inner join @Events e
        on u.UserId = e.UserId
            and e.EventDate >= @JoinDate
    where u.JoinDate = @JoinDate
)
select 
    UserCount = count(distinct b.UserId),
    EventDate = a.EventDate
from src a
inner join src b
    on a.EventDate <= b.EventDate
group by a.EventDate
order by UserCount desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, since we're working with dates, I'd build a [Calendar Table](https://www.sqlshack.com/designing-a-calendar-table/) table to make things much easier:

```
create table Calendar
(
    id int primary key identity,
    [date] datetime,
    [day] as datepart(day, [date]) persisted,
    [month] as datepart(month, [date]) persisted,
    [year] as datepart(year, [date]) persisted,

    day_of_year as datepart(dayofyear, [date]) persisted,
    [week] as datepart(week, [date]),

    day_name as datename(dw, [date]),

    is_weekend as 
    case when datepart(dw, [date]) = 7 or datepart(dw, [date]) = 1 
    then 1 else 0 end,

    [quarter] as datepart(quarter, [date]) persisted        
)

go

declare @date datetime
set @date = '1-1-2010'

while @date <= '12-31-2100'
begin

    insert Calendar select @date
    set @date = dateadd(day, 1, @date)

end
```

So, your schema will probably look something like this:

```
create table Member
(
    id int primary key identity,
    name nvarchar(100) mot null,
    joined int foreign key references Calendar not null
)

create table MemberActivityType
(
    id int primary key identity,
    name varchar(50) not null
)

insert MemberActivityType 
    select 'Open' union
    select 'Close' union
    select 'Move'

create table MemberActivity
(
    id int primary key identity,
    member_id int foreign key references Member,
    activity_id int foreign key references MemberActivityType,
    [date] int foreign key references Calendar not null
)
```

Now, anytime that you need an "if-then" in your query, the `Apply` operator is probably the first tool that you should consider. It has the following form:

```
 select * from Q [outer|cross] apply P(q1...qn)
```

where `P` and `Q` are relations (tables), `q1..qn` are an attributes (columns) of `Q` and `P(q1..qn)` represents a query on P with respect to the values of `q1...qn` of some row of `Q`. This means that `P(q1..qn)` is evaluated for each result from `Q`

Hence, this function will yield the results that you want:

```
create function UnboundedRetention
(
    @join_date int
)
returns @results table(users int, date datetime)
begin       

with Q as
(select K.member_id, K.date anchor from MemberActivity K outer apply

        (select J.member_id, J.date from MemberActivity J 
            where J.date = K.date + 1
            and J.member_id = K.id) L                

        outer apply
                (
                    select A.date from MemberActivity A
                    where A.date > L.date and A.member_id = L.member_id
                ) M

        where K.date >=  @join_date)

    insert @results

        select L.c, C.date from Calendar C inner join Q on Q.anchor = C.id

    cross apply
        (
            select count(M.id) c from Member M where M.id in (select member_id from Q K where K.anchor >= C.id)
        ) L

    return
end
```

In this case, `Q` is a common table expression meaning  "For each date on or after `@join_date` in which a member did something `(K)`, return the *immediate* following date in which that member did something `(L)` and also for each date in `L`, return all subsequent dates in which the member did something `(M)`.

Then, for each date in `Q`, we return the count of all members that did something on or after that date Q`.

Kindly test out the [solution](https://gist.github.com/noblethrasher/83eace8e1797fdebc83aba1ceeb997a9) for yourself; it's wrapped in an uncomitted transaction to make it easy.